# Finding value of $a^bb^dd^ee^a$

Tags: calculus, functions

If $f(x)$ is an onto function such that $f:R\to [-1,2], f(x) = \frac{x^2+ 9bx +17}{ax^3+x^2+bx+33}$ and $f'(d)=f'(e)=0$ where $a,b \in R$ and $e \gt d$. Find the value of $a^bb^dd^ee^a$.

Need hints.

Comment: Clearly $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.  Because it is onto we have $f(d)=-1, f(e)=2$ or the other way around depending on the sign of $a$.  I'll bet $a,b,d,e$ are all small integers or perhaps rationals with small numerator and denominator, but not very much.  Play with it a while and report back.

Comment: @RossMillikan Even I was able to conclude this much information. I tried differentiating it, putting values in the original function. There are four equation and four variables but they are too tough to solve. 2 equations are obtained by putting $d$ and $e$ in the function and making them equal to $-1$ and $2$ respectively. The other two equations are obtained the differentiating and making it equal to $0$ for $d$ and $e$.

Comment: You should show what progress you have made.  It is easier to proceed without having to rediscover what you have already done.  It is also easier to find the proper level of response.  If you have four equations you should show them.

Comment: @RossMillikan $\frac{d^2+9bd+17}{ad^3+d^2+bd+33}=-1$, $\frac{e^2+9be+17}{ae^3+e^2+be+33}=2$. Two more obtained by differentiating. $(ad^3+d^2+bd+33)(2d+9b)=(d^2+9bd+17)(3ad^2+2d+b)$ and $(ae^3+e^2+be+33)(2e+9b)=(e^2+9be+17)(3ae^2+2e+b)$. How should I solve them? I have assumed $a \gt 0$.

Comment: Edit your question and post your work in your question post, not in the comments.

Comment: I've got that it is impossible to find real $a,b$ such that the function is onto $[-1,2]$. The best possible is around $[-1,1.61]$. Are you sure that everything is correct?

Comment: @A.Γ. Yeah, I am quite sure. My friend has solved this question. As soon as he send me the solution, I will post it here